Change y axis scaling on a Seaborn Heatmap
I am at the final stage of displaying a heatmap within a facetgrid. When I am presenting the data, some of the index values may or may not be present for the row / column combination. I would like to display these as blanks and adjust the heatmap entries accordingly. Unfortunately, I cannot get all values (1 to 10) to display on the y axis matching what I have in the heatmap as per below. Any data values not present should display blank rows in the heatmap.
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import numpy as np

waitremap = {'0-2':0,'3-4':1,'5-6':2,'7-8':3,'9-10':4,'11-12':5}


df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Spec':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                    'Wait':[5,6,2,4,1,2,11,12],
                   'MyClass':[1,4,7,10,1,2,3,4],
                   'WaitClass':['5-6','5-6','0-2','3-4','0-2','0-2','11-12','11-12'],
                  })


heatdf = (pd.crosstab(index=df.MyClass,columns=df.WaitClass,values=df.Wait,aggfunc='count',normalize='index')
          #.assign(colnum =1)
          .reset_index()
         )

heatdf.index = heatdf.MyClass
heatdf1 =(heatdf
            .drop(columns=['MyClass'])
          )



#g3 = sns.heatmap(heatdf1,cmap='Blues')
g2 = sns.FacetGrid(heatdf1,height=5,sharey=False,sharex=False)
myheatmap = g2.map_dataframe(sns.heatmap)

Any help is much appreciated.
enter image description here

If I understand correctly, using reindex:
heatdf1 = (heatdf.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(1, 11))
                 .drop(columns='MyClass')
                 .fillna(0))

Output:

Or perhaps:
heatdf1 = heatdf.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(1, 11)).drop(columns='MyClass')

Output:


With fillna(np.nan) the missing rows would be blank (the white background) instead of the zero-color?

@JohanC or just leaving out fillna entirely, but I wasn't sure what OP wanted.

This is exactly what I was looking for - elegant and simple. Thank you very much
